# how can you create a separate component in angular?

Tags: angular

how can you create a component that does not respect the design of app.module(that is, a separate component that has its own template) in angular ?

Comment: [`ng generate component [name]`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-component)

Comment: did you get anything from my answer...

Comment: @ganesh045  added example please...

Answer (score 0):

create a component and it's template from this command from angular-cli
`ng g c componentName` and create a `index.ts` file in the same folder and that will used to export your component.

**index.ts**

```
export { componentName } from './componentName.component.ts';
```

To use this component's template add your `ComponentName` in the `providers` of the their module in where ever you want in your project.

Comment: this component depends on app.component.
what is wanted is to have a component that does not depend on app.component and that when the component is called, only that component is shown, and not the others that are being called by app.component